# How to put a cursor in the middle of the screen?

Tags: game-engine, camera

How could I add a pointer at the middle of the screen, where my mouse is fixed there? Something like this:

[image]

Comment: This includes multiple questions, and thus should be split.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from [this method](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/12191/can-you-make-a-custom-mouse-cursor-for-the-game-engine), if the "cursor" always stays in the middle of the screen, another way would be to parent an object to the camera (<kbd>⎈ Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

[image]