# Blender Game Engine - Mouse Click Location

Tags: game-engine, particles

Does anyone know an easy way to have blender spawn particles based on the mouse's location in 2D space on screen? I want to have the user click the mouse and create bubbles that float upwards from that spawn location.

Thanks.

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/2112/599

Comment: A point in 2D is a line in 3D. Therefore you need to tell what the third coordinate of the desired position is. e.g. at the object under the cursor, at a defined distance to the camera ...